# POST http://URL 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I am trying to make a post request through Angular. My code looks as follows,

Javascript Code looks like:

GET:

```
$scope.getRecord = function() {
    debugger;
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'SomeURL'
        }).then(function(response) {
          debugger;
          $scope.mainEntity = response.data.anEntity;
        }, function(error) {
          $scope.content = "something went wrong"
        });
      };
```

Post:

```
$scope.save = function() {

        debugger;
        var body = JSON.stringify({
          "xyzaa": $scope.value.xyzaa || "One fielfd of its",
          "xyzbb": $scope.value.xyzbb || One fielfd of its,
          "xyzcc": $scope.value.xyzcc || "One fielfd of its",
          "xyzaaa": $scope.value.xyzaaa || "One fielfd of its"

        });
        var request = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'Some URL',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
          },
          data: body
        };
        $http(request).then(function (result) {
          debugger;
          $scope.getRecord();
        }, function (error) {
          debugger;
          console.log(error)
          alert("error")
        })

      };
```

Well, I can see that the post request returns the data that I have done in a JSON Format, yet am receiving the error:

POST http://localhost:xyz/xyz/a (Unprocessable Entity)

Object {data: Object, status: 422, config: Object, statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"}.

I can see that data that am being posting is getting in the data key and I can see the data that I have passed, yet I get this error and it doesnt change in the api

Comment: What is that `debugger`s all around your code?

Comment: Thats just me trying to find whether my request is being passed or not